# Homepage content overlapping sidebar

Tags: reactjs

Screenshot is below of what is currently happening

[image]

As you can see, the homepage is currently overlapping underneath the sidebar, with the homepage content partially hidden. I would like the homepage content to be to the right of sidebar, and neither overlap, as I plan for a data table to exist to the right of the sidebar.

How can I achieve this state?

home

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Sidebar from "./Sidebar.js";

export default class Home extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
          <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
            <Sidebar />
            <h1>Right of sidebar page </h1>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

sidebar

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { Link, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import Logo from '../Logo.svg'

import '../sidebar.css';
 
    const sidebarNavItems = [
       {
            display: 'Home',
            to: '/'
        
        },
        {
            display: 'Blog',
            to: 'Blog/'
        }
    ]

    const Sidebar = () => {
        const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);
        const [stepHeight, setStepHeight] = useState(0);
        const sidebarRef = useRef();
        const indicatorRef = useRef();
        const location = useLocation();
    
        useEffect(() => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                const sidebarItem = sidebarRef.current.querySelector('.sidebar__menu__item');
                indicatorRef.current.style.height = `${sidebarItem.clientHeight}px`;
                setStepHeight(sidebarItem.clientHeight);
            }, 50);
        }, []);

         // change active index
    useEffect(() => {
        const curPath = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1];
        const activeItem = sidebarNavItems.findIndex(item => item.section === curPath);
        setActiveIndex(curPath.length === 0 ? 0 : activeItem);
    }, [location]);
    

    return (
      <div className='sidebar'>
      <div className="sidebar__logo">
      <div><img src = {Logo} alt='Logo'className='Logo' /></div>
      </div>
      <div ref={sidebarRef} className="sidebar__menu">
          <div
              ref={indicatorRef}
              className="sidebar__menu__indicator"
              style={{
                  transform: `translateX(-50%) translateY(${activeIndex * stepHeight}px)`
              }}
          ></div>
          {
              sidebarNavItems.map((item, index) => (
                  <Link to={item.to} key={index}>
                      <div className={`sidebar__menu__item ${activeIndex === index ? 'active' : ''}`}>
                          <div className="sidebar__menu__item__icon">
                              {item.icon}
                          </div>
                          <div className="sidebar__menu__item__text">
                              {item.display}
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </Link>
              ))
          }
      </div>
  </div>);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making your home like this

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Sidebar from "./Sidebar.js";

export default class Home extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
          <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
            <div className="left"   >
               <Sidebar />
            </div>
            <div  className="right">
                 <h1>Right of sidebar page </h1>
            </div>
            
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Adjust a bit of styling , hope this solves your issue .

Comment: Still does not work unofrtuantley

Comment: How would you format CSS for classname Right and Left?

Comment: can you create a sandbox and send the link here ?

Comment: for className left just add width : 30% , height : 100vh ;

Comment: for className right add width 70% ,  heighth : 100vh ;

Comment: Hey , please upvote if the solution works , as it will help others to find the working solution quickly .
Thank you .